# Input Tex file in knitr file

Tags: knitr

I am showing a simple example here just to frame the question.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<>>=
library('ggplot2')
dataset <- diamonds
@

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c}
  \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Columns} \\\hline \hline
  dataset & \Sexpr{length(colnames(dataset))} \\
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Repeated table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Now I am repeating this table (exact table) multiple times over the file. (Imagine replacing dataset with another set before calling this table).

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<>>=
library('ggplot2')
dataset <- diamonds;
@

\input{table-file.tex}

\end{document}
```

I am putting the entire tabular part into this file, and then input it several places. But I can't get this to work. I was wondering if this is possible? any better approaches to make this table "modular".

Thanks

Comment: related/possible duplicate: [Building TeX file from knitr Rnw as child of larger parent TeX file to use R objects and output](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128668/building-tex-file-from-knitr-rnw-as-child-of-larger-parent-tex-file-to-use-r-obj)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example using the knitr child file process as per the knitr documentation yihui.name/knitr/demo/child.

First the new main file which I called 'knitr01.Rnw'

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<>>=
library('ggplot2')
dataset <- diamonds
@

<<child='child-knitr01.Rnw'>>=
@

<<>>=
dataset<-mtcars
@

<<child='child-knitr01.Rnw'>>=
@
\end{document}
```

Note that I inputed the child twice each with a different dataset.

And the child file which I named 'child-knitr01.Rnw'.

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c}
  \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Columns} \\\hline \hline
  dataset & \Sexpr{length(colnames(dataset))} \\
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Repeated table}
\end{table}
```

When run first through 'knit' and then through 'pdflatex' it results in

[image]

To continue the demonstration for completeness, this also allows child files to input grandchildren.

The knitr01.Rnw is changed as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<>>=
library('ggplot2')
dataset <- diamonds
title="These are diamonds"
@

<<child='child-knitr01.Rnw'>>=
@

<<>>=
dataset<-mtcars
title="These are cars"
@

<<child='child-knitr01.Rnw'>>=
@

\end{document}
```

Here is the revised 'child-knitr01.Rnw' file

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c}
  \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Columns} \\\hline \hline
  dataset & \Sexpr{length(colnames(dataset))} \\
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{\Sexpr{paste(substr(capture.output(print(title)),5,50))}}
  % The 5 is to remove some leading R stuff (try with 1 to see why)
  % The 50 is chosen to be longer than the string
\end{table}

<<child='grand-child-knitr01.Rnw'>>=
@
```

And here is the 'grand-child-knitr01.Rnw' file

```
Demonstration that you can call on 'grandchildren' files with knitr.

<<>>=
names(dataset)  
@
```

And the output is:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. Just to follow-up, is it possible to pass parameters to the child-chunk? That way I can pass label name for this table. I can't find any info. in the documentation.

Comment: @tallharish Revised file to pass a caption from inside the R-Chunk

Comment: @tallharish If you are planning on building large tabular constructs from data obtained inside R then I recommend to look at the various packages in R that generate LaTeX code directly.  This will greatly improve the appearance of the final project.  More questions on this are best answered on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r