# Using LuaLaTeX and knitr together

Tags: luatex, r, knitr

I would like to include R results in a LuaLaTeX document, which I prefer over XeLaTeX mainly because of the greater support of the package `microtype`.
Do you know whether and how is it possible?

Moreover, for more structured documents, I like to call the chapters' .tex files with the command `\input` in a master file, which is then compiled. Therefore, I would also like to know, in case you have a solution to the first problem, if it allows such tree structure.

I am especially interested in solutions that refer to Sweave files compilation.

Comment: Regarding your second question, the question "[Building TeX file from knitr Rnw as child of larger parent TeX file to use R objects and output](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/128668/32888)" and its answers might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

There's an option to change the LaTeX engine with R Markdown:

https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/pdf_document_format.html#latex_engine

Comment: that is definetely interesting to compile Rmarkdown files, however I am interested in compiling Sweave files - I will update the question text.

Answer (score 2):

The following works in RStudio, the front-end I use for R programming:

First I created a `.Renviron` file containing the following line:

```
RSTUDIO_PDFLATEX="lualatex"
```

This sets the RStudio environment variable to for the TeX engine.

This file is normally in your home folder, i.e., `~/.Renviron`

Then the default engine that `knitr` (and Sweave, I assume) will use will be `LuaLaTeX`.

Note that you *cannot* use the `% !TeX program = LuaLaTeX` directive since this line is parsed by RStudio, and it only recognizes pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX as valid engines. These engines, however, will still work on a per-file basis using `% !TeX program = pdfLaTeX` or `% !TeX program = XeLaTeX`.

As to your second question, yes, your `.Rnw` file behaves just like any LaTeX document, and `\input` and similar commands are possible.

Comment: I've submitted a pull request to RStudio to support `LuaLaTeX` in the `!TeX` comment: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/pull/13812 Thanks!

Comment: @YihuiXie Thanks for the edit and the pull request!