# How to use Sweave (knitr) with LuaLaTex?

Tags: luatex, r, knitr, sweave, rstudio

This is a duplicate of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413535/using-lualatex-and-knitr-together) 5 year old question, because the answers there don't work (for me).

Has someone managed to get knitr for Sweave documents (not RMarkdown) running with LuaLaTex as an engine? RStudio only lets you choose between PdfLaTex und XeLaTex, which unfortunately don't work for my purposes.

I'm running Mac OS 14.0 (Sonoma). Setting the environment variable `RSTUDIO_PDFLATEX = "LuaLaTeX"` in `~/.Rprofile` unfortunately has no effect.

I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just updated the answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/419885/9128, which was mostly correct but just had a typo. You need to set

```sh
RSTUDIO_PDFLATEX=lualatex
```

in `.Renviron` instead of `.Rprofile`. The former is for setting environment variables for R, and the latter is to provide an R script to run before each R session starts up. Setting environment variables in the latter will not have any effect (it didn't throw an error just because `RSTUDIO_PDFLATEX = "LuaLaTeX"` happens to be valid R code, and you created a global variable `RSTUDIO_PDFLATEX` in your R session; I'd recommend you delete it from `.Rprofile`).

Also remember to restart R after you change `.Renviron` so RStudio can pick up the new environment variable.